# I have problem with padding text next to an img

Tags: css, html

I want to place text next to an image and add padding to it. I have both text and image in one box, so that may be problem. I also need site to be mobile friendly.

Here is my code:

```css
.content-title {
  font-size: 50px;
}

#section-a ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

#tiso {
  position: static;
  padding: 0px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 800px;
}

#tiso_text {
  padding: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-a" class="grid">
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <ul class="obr">
      <img src="IMG/tiso.png" alt="Tiso-main" id="tiso">
      <h1 class="content-title">Jozef Tiso</h1>
      <li class="textcontent">
        <p id="tiso_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate obcaecati et porro quidem iure, odio.
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Now, it works when the browser is resized to minimum, but it doesn't work on full. I know why, see image below, I just don't know how to fix that.

[Image of what I have, and what I need.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaIY9.png)

Comment: i think the best way to do it is with flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here is my solution, i hope its that what you wanted..

```css
 .content-title {
  font-size: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}


.item {
 max-width: 300px;
 float: left;
 padding: 20px 3rem;

 }

 #tiso {
  position: static;
  padding: 0px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 800px;
  display: block;
 }

  #tiso_text {

  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<section id="section-a" class="grid">
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="IMG/tiso.png" alt="Tiso-main" id="tiso">

      
      <div class="item">
        <h1 class="content-title">Jozef Tiso</h1>
        <p id="tiso_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
          Voluptate obcaecati et porro quidem iure, odio.
        </p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```